# Why the same query with UNION operator costs much less than with UNION ALL?

Tags: plsql, union, union-all

The cost of my test query is 910 in case I use UNION and it is 46726 in case I use UNION ALL. I use PL/SQLDeveloper. As I understand UNION ALL should cost less as it is not spend time for deleting duplicate rows. Could someone explain to me why the query with UNION is much faster?

```
My test query is:
       SELECT RELATED_ORDR.ORDR_ID ID
              ,RELATED_ORDR.ORDR_ID
              ,EXT_TYPE TYPE
              ,DECODE(RELATION, 1, GOR_CONTINGENCY, CONTINGENCY) CONTINGENCY_TYPE
              ,RELATION
              ,DECODE(SIGN(ORDR_QTY),1,'B',-1,'S') BSS
              ,ORDR_QTY QUANTITY
              ,FXRE2_ORDER_AUDIT_REPORT.getOrderStatus(EXT_STATUS) STATUS
              ,STATUS_DT DT
              ,TRADE_ID TICKET
              ,CASE WHEN EXT_TYPE IN ('OR', 'CR', 'RE', 'RTE') THEN RATE2
                    ELSE RATE
               END RATE
              ,OFFER_ID
          FROM
              (SELECT DISTINCT RO.ID ORDR_ID
                              ,RO.CONTINGENCY_TYPE CONTINGENCY
                              ,DECODE(RO.ID, GOR.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY, 1,
                                      DECODE(RO.CONTINGENCY_ID, GOR.CONTINGENCY_ID, 3,
                                             DECODE(RO.CONTINGENCY_ID, GOR.ORDR_ID, 2,
                                                    DECODE(RO.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY, GOR.ORDR_ID, 2)))) RELATION
                              ,GOR.CONTINGENCY_TYPE GOR_CONTINGENCY
                 FROM /*GIVEN_ORDR GOR --GIVEN*/
                      (SELECT to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,1)) as ORDR_ID
                             ,to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,2)) as ORDR_ID_PRIMARY
                             ,to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,3)) as CONTINGENCY_ID
                             ,          regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,4)  as CONTINGENCY_TYPE
                             ,to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,5)) as ACCT_ID
                         FROM dual t) GOR --GIVEN
                      ,ORDR_HIST RO --RELATED/LINKED
                WHERE GOR.ACCT_ID = RO.ACCT_ID
                  AND RO.ID != GOR.ORDR_ID-- NOT GIVEN ORDR
                  AND RO.STATUS_DT IS NOT NULL
                  AND (RO.ID = GOR.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY
                       OR RO.CONTINGENCY_ID = GOR.CONTINGENCY_ID
                       OR RO.CONTINGENCY_ID = GOR.ORDR_ID
                       OR RO.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY = GOR.ORDR_ID)) RELATED_ORDR
              ,ORDR_HIST
         WHERE ORDR_HIST.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ORDR_HIST WHERE ID = RELATED_ORDR.ORDR_ID)
         UNION ALL
        SELECT RELATED_ORDR.ORDR_ID ID -- just for compatibility, it is not used
              ,RELATED_ORDR.ORDR_ID
              ,EXT_TYPE TYPE
              ,DECODE(RELATION, 1, GOR_CONTINGENCY, CONTINGENCY) CONTINGENCY_TYPE
              ,RELATION
              ,DECODE(SIGN(ORDR_QTY),1,'B',-1,'S') BSS
              ,ORDR_QTY QUANTITY
              ,FXRE2_ORDER_AUDIT_REPORT.getOrderStatus(EXT_STATUS) STATUS
              ,STATUS_DT DT
              ,TRADE_ID TICKET
              ,CASE WHEN EXT_TYPE IN ('OR', 'CR', 'RE', 'RTE') THEN RATE2
                    ELSE RATE
               END RATE
              ,OFFER_ID
          FROM
              (SELECT DISTINCT RO.ID ORDR_ID
                              ,RO.CONTINGENCY_TYPE CONTINGENCY
                              ,DECODE(RO.ID, GOR.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY, 1,
                                      DECODE(RO.CONTINGENCY_ID, GOR.CONTINGENCY_ID, 3,
                                             DECODE(RO.CONTINGENCY_ID, GOR.ORDR_ID, 2,
                                                    DECODE(RO.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY, GOR.ORDR_ID, 2)))) RELATION
                              ,GOR.CONTINGENCY_TYPE GOR_CONTINGENCY
                 FROM /*GIVEN_ORDR GOR --GIVEN*/
                      (SELECT to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,1)) as ORDR_ID
                             ,to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,2)) as ORDR_ID_PRIMARY
                             ,to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,3)) as CONTINGENCY_ID
                             ,          regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,4)  as CONTINGENCY_TYPE
                             ,to_number(regexp_substr('21153473;21151187;21151187;3;5240435','[^;]+',1,5)) as ACCT_ID
                         FROM dual t) GOR --GIVEN
                      ,ORDR_HIST RO --RELATED/LINKED
                WHERE GOR.ACCT_ID = RO.ACCT_ID
                  AND RO.ID != GOR.ORDR_ID-- NOT GIVEN ORDR
                  AND RO.STATUS_DT IS NOT NULL
                  AND (RO.ID = GOR.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY
                       OR RO.CONTINGENCY_ID = GOR.CONTINGENCY_ID
                       OR RO.CONTINGENCY_ID = GOR.ORDR_ID
                       OR RO.ORDR_ID_PRIMARY = GOR.ORDR_ID)) RELATED_ORDR
              ,ORDR
         WHERE ORDR.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ORDR_HIST WHERE ID = RELATED_ORDR.ORDR_ID)                  
         ORDER BY ID;}

The plans of 2 queries are:
UNION 0.078sec                 COST    CARD.   BYTES   CPU COST      IO COST   TEMP SPACE   
SELECT STATEMENT                910 4528    271695  214479428   905 
UNION ALL 0.032sec
SELECT STATEMENT                46726   3194117 198026200 970740819 46626   


SELECT STATEMENT                910 4528    271695  214479428   905 

 SORT UNIQUE            909 4528    271695  172294190   905 
  UNION-ALL                             
   HASH JOIN            551 1   75  45895432    550 
    NESTED LOOPS            551 1   75  45895432    550 
     NESTED LOOPS           551 1   75  45895432    550 
      STATISTICS COLLECTOR                              
       NESTED LOOPS         452 1   33  45187910    451 
        VIEW    U1R2_DEV        353 1   20  44482687    352 
         HASH UNIQUE            353 1   18  44482687    352 
          NESTED LOOPS          352 1   18  4775046 352 
           FAST DUAL            2   1       7271    2   
           PARTITION RANGE ALL          350 1   18  4767775 350 
            TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED   U1R2    ORDR_HIST   350 1   18  4767775 350 
             INDEX RANGE SCAN   U1R2    OH_ACCT_ID_IDX  101 1285        977115  101 
        VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE   SYS VW_SQ_1 99  1   13  705223  99  
         FILTER                             
          SORT AGGREGATE                1   6           
           PARTITION RANGE ALL          99  1   6   705223  99  
            INDEX RANGE SCAN    U1R2    ORDR_HIST2_ACCT_ID  99  1   6   705223  99  
      PARTITION RANGE ALL           98  1       698951  98  
       INDEX RANGE SCAN U1R2    ORDR_HIST2_ACCT_ID  98  1       698951  98  
     TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID  U1R2    ORDR_HIST   99  1   42  707523  99  
    PARTITION RANGE ALL         99  1   42  707523  99  
     TABLE ACCESS FULL  U1R2    ORDR_HIST   99  1   42  707523  99  
   NESTED LOOPS         356 1   60  44506492    355 
    NESTED LOOPS            356 1   60  44506492    355 
     VIEW   U1R2_DEV        353 1   20  44482687    352 
      HASH UNIQUE           353 1   18  44482687    352 
       NESTED LOOPS         352 1   18  4775046 352 
        FAST DUAL           2   1       7271    2   
        PARTITION RANGE ALL         350 1   18  4767775 350 
         TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED  U1R2    ORDR_HIST   350 1   18  4767775 350 
          INDEX RANGE SCAN  U1R2    OH_ACCT_ID_IDX  101 1285        977115  101 
     INDEX RANGE SCAN   U1R2    ORDR_AIM    2   1       15293   2   
      PARTITION RANGE ALL MIN/MAX               1   6           
       SORT AGGREGATE               1   6           
        FIRST ROW           99  1   6   705223  99  
         INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX) U1R2    ORDR_HIST2_ACCT_ID  99  1   6   705223  99  
    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID U1R2    ORDR    3   1   40  23804   3   


UNION ALL 0.032sec

SELECT STATEMENT                46726   3194117 198026200   3970740819  46626   
 SORT ORDER BY          808 3194117 198026200   89696701    806 269771000
  UNION-ALL                             
   NESTED LOOPS         452 1   62  45190210    451 
    NESTED LOOPS            452 1   62  45190210    451 
     VIEW   U1R2_DEV        353 1   20  44482687    352 
      HASH UNIQUE           353 1   18  44482687    352 
       NESTED LOOPS         352 1   18  4775046 352 
        FAST DUAL           2   1       7271    2   
        PARTITION RANGE ALL         350 1   18  4767775 350 
         TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED  U1R2    ORDR_HIST   350 1   18  4767775 350 
          INDEX RANGE SCAN  U1R2    OH_ACCT_ID_IDX  101 1285        977115  101 
     PARTITION RANGE ALL            98  1       698951  98  
      INDEX RANGE SCAN  U1R2    ORDR_HIST2_ACCT_ID  98  1       698951  98  
       PARTITION RANGE ALL MIN/MAX              1   6           
        SORT AGGREGATE              1   6           
         FIRST ROW          99  1   6   705223  99  
          INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)    U1R2    ORDR_HIST2_ACCT_ID  99  1   6   705223  99  
    TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID   U1R2    ORDR_HIST   99  1   42  707523  99  
   NESTED LOOPS         356 1   60  44506492    355 
    NESTED LOOPS            356 1   60  44506492    355 
     VIEW   U1R2_DEV        353 1   20  44482687    352 
      HASH UNIQUE           353 1   18  44482687    352 
       NESTED LOOPS         352 1   18  4775046 352 
        FAST DUAL           2   1       7271    2   
        PARTITION RANGE ALL         350 1   18  4767775 350 
         TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID BATCHED  U1R2    ORDR_HIST   350 1   18  4767775 350 
          INDEX RANGE SCAN  U1R2    OH_ACCT_ID_IDX  101 1285        977115  101 
     INDEX RANGE SCAN   U1R2    ORDR_AIM    2   1       15293   2   
      PARTITION RANGE ALL MIN/MAX               1   6           
       SORT AGGREGATE               1   6           
        FIRST ROW           99  1   6   705223  99  
         INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX) U1R2    ORDR_HIST2_ACCT_ID  99  1   6   705223  99  
    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID U1R2    ORDR    3   1   40  23804   3
```

Answer (score 1):

the difference between Union and Union all is as follows.

UNION insures you get DISTINCT records from both the tables.
UNION ALL pulls out all records from both the tables with duplicates.

The reason your union all query is cost is higher could be Oracle is fetching more rows,
Please check the explain plan for both the queries and you may see that the Union all query might be doing more processing than the union query.

Answer (score 0):

1. The term "Cost" is not always associated with time taken by the query to execute. "Cost" has a broader meaning more than just time taken to execute the query. "Cost" includes physical as well as logical resources.
2. UNION operator does two jobs: Finding distinct records based on the columns SELECTed and sorting the result set. Basically, UNION sorts the result set. Thats why you see "SORT UNIQUE" as in the EXPLAIN PLAN.
3. UNION ALL does not have burden of finding unique records and sorting them. Its job is the easiest. Append records from 2nd query with the 1st query and return the results. Thats why it takes lesser time to retrieve when compared to the SELECT with UNION operator. Very important point which you need to look at is the physical and logical resource used by UNION ALL when compared to UNION.
   SELECT STATEMENT                46726   3194117 198026200 970740819 46626
4. Most of the times, Oracle DB finds ways of doing the things in an easier way. For Oracle DB will be happier if you give it query with UNION ALL compared to UNION. Thats why, time taken by UNION is more compared to UNION ALL though UNION ALL uses more amount of available resources compared to UNION.

UNION 0.078sec ---> More time taken to execute.
UNION ----> Less amount of resources used.
COST    CARD.   BYTES   CPU COST      IO COST   TEMP SPACE
SELECT STATEMENT                910 4528    271695  214479428   905

UNION ALL 0.032sec ---> Less time taken to execute.
UNION ALL ---> More amount of resources used.
COST    CARD.   BYTES   CPU COST      IO COST   TEMP SPACE
SELECT STATEMENT                46726   3194117 198026200 970740819 46626

Hope this clarifies your doubt.